# What's meaning of color buffer and texture format in cocos2d?

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, game-engine, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d.We use

`CCGLView *glView = 
          [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
              pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565    //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
              depthFormat:0 //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
           preserveBackbuffer:NO
               sharegroup:nil
            multiSampling:NO
          numberOfSamples:0];`

to create an CCGLView with a color buffer, and a depth buffer. But what the buffer meaning?

And we use

`[CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];`

to set texture format. What the meaning of it.

I can not find the relationship and different between buffer and texture format. And how they work?

**We set a 16-bit buffer but set a 32-bit texture format. Why?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to these links:

**Explanation of what buffers are and how they apply to Cocos2d**
http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2012/11/optimize-memory-usage-bundle-size-cocos2d-app/  http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter10.html

**cocos2d documentation on buffers**
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:setup_buffers

**cocos2d documentation on RGBA8888**
http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/61